# My external monitor flickers when using with Vista, but not with XP/Linux

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, external-display

I bought a new Dell Monitor ST 2410 model (24 inch). It works great when I connect my XP laptop to it or my Linux box. But when I connect it to my HP Laptop (Dv 6000 series) which has Vista on it. The monitor flickers a lot. 
Tried out all modes/frequencies but didn't help me. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you connecting it via DVI or VGA (D-SUB)?

Comment: I am using VGA, there's no DVI port on my HP Laptop

Comment: Just check if there is any specific driver for Vista for your monitor. It looks like a display driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost definitely the HP laptop and not Vista or a setting.

Try it without the HP plugged into the wall and see if that clears it up.

If it does, it's electrical interference in the laptop itself.

I've seen that problem with several different makes and models of laptops over the years, sometimes a replacement AC/DC pack fixes it, sometimes it has to be replaced with a different power pack that provides more amperage.

Often it's the motherboard itself (or a graphics daughterboard), and when it is it unfortunately sometimes takes two or three replacement boards before you get one that doesn't do it.

The good news is this IS a problem that's covered by warranty; so if you have any warranty left, contact HP to find the nearest authorized repair centre and arrange to take them both the laptop and the monitor to show them what your talking about.

If you don't have any warranty left, go the route of getting/trying a bigger AC/DC adapter (same voltage ratings, more amperage) first, as it's the easiest and probably least expensive.

BTW, you're not the only one with that notebook and a flickering external monitor -- see [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=178387) for one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an external device plugged into that HP Laptop? I have an external HD which causes my monitor to flicker. switching the HD off, solves the problem immediately.

Took me weeks to discover (after I installed and uninstalled graphics and monitor drivers in all imaginable ways)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a driver issue to me, have you checked in device manager to see if the correct drivers are loaded for the display adapter?